# pasar elemento de datagridview a listbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

saludos estoy tratando de enviar datos a un listbox desde un datagridview y no me permite. cual seria la forma correcta. yo lo estoy tratando de hacer asi:

```
    private void dgvProceConsulta_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        FichaConsulta fc = new FichaConsulta();
        fc.lbProce.Items.Add = dgvProceConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    }
```

pero me dice que no se puede asignar porque es grupo de metodos.

Comment: ya vi que la forma correcta es         fc.lbProce.Items.Add(dgvProceConsulta.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString()); pero igual no me funciona

Comment: si quieres enviar de listbox a datagrid, ese codigo deberia de ir en el evento del listbox y no del datagrid.

Comment: lo puse mal, ahora lo corrijo es de datagridview a listbox

Comment: Amigo, creo que necesitamos mas informacion. Que es FichaConsulta? Es un formulario? Y cuando intenta `items.Add(...)`, hay mensaje de error? Puede editar su pregunta y agrega estas informaciones.

Comment: ya lo solucione era un error de sintaxis a fin de cuentas. como elimino esta pregunta?